# Displaying the Alphabet in HTML Tables using PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I'll keep this as brief as possible.

How would I go about displaying all 26 letters of the alphabet into a table (6 rows with 4 columns and the last row with 2 columns) using PHP?

Each table block is supposed to contain a letter of the alphabet, so for example:

A B C D

E F G H

I J K L

M N O P

Q R S T

U V W X

Y Z

I am supposed to write the function in PHP and I'm assuming echoing it into an HTML table.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may want to look into loops.

Comment: Yes loops is what I figured. I have very little experience in PHP but I am being asked to help out a developer at work and they want me to do this and I really have no idea how to haha

Answer (score 9):

This could be an implementation

```
// All letters of the alphabet
$alphabet = range('A', 'Z'); // range returns an array

$table = '<table>';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($alphabet); $i++) {

    // Every fourth element start a new table line
    if ($i % 4 == 0)
        $table .= '<tr>';

    $table .= '<td>' . $alphabet[$i] . '</td>';

    // Every fourth element end a table line. Do not forget the last element
    if (($i-3) % 4 == 0 || $i+1 == count($alphabet))
        $table .= '</tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';

// Do whatever you want with the output string
echo $table;
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! Now I just got to look it over to make sure I clearly understand what is going on in case they ask me haha

Comment: Why use `$alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';`? Why not `$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');`

Comment: Good one, I added your suggestion! I did not realize `range` can deal with non-numbers. On the other hand it is less readable for a beginner.

Comment: Shouldn’t you replace `strlen` with `sizeof`?

Comment: No, `sizeof` is an alias of `count` for counting arrays or objects. Probably `mb_strlen()` is better than `strlen()` if the op wants to use special characters because `strlen()` counts the bytes and `mb_strlen()` the amount of characters.

Comment: See [this](http://codepad.org/Dp4dMkhL) and also [this](http://codepad.org/6VKOiM0H). When you changed your code from `$alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';` to `$alphabet = range('A', 'Z');`, you should have replaced all instances of `strlen` with `sizeof` for the simple reason that `$alphabet` is no more a string – it’s an array.

Comment: Or you may go for `$alphabet = implode(range('A', 'Z'));`.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked that fact when you pointed out replacing the variable. Damn type boxing. ;)

Comment: The edited code has an error in it...it says "strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string,"

Comment: Yes, I edited it a few minutes ago because we changed the implementation of `$alphabet` and I forgot to adjust that part. If you copy the current code, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

A for loop and modulus operator should do the trick.

```
$string = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$length = strlen($string);

echo "<table>";

for ($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    if( $i % 4 == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$string[$i]."</td>";
    if( $i % 4 == 3 || $i==$length ) echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: At the end it would be $i+1 == $length, I nearly trapped in too. ;)